# Fill multiple parents with border onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay so what I have is a div -> table -> row, and 3x columns each with their own div and image inside the div (the div is so the image doesn't get clipped with border-radius). What I want to do is expand the border width till the parent div, above the table, is filled with the border. When I tried to do this the border stops and expands each column. I'll post some photos and code below.
Sorry for the vague explanation I just don't know how to explain it.. Any help and suggestions of better ways to do it are much appreciated! =D

Code:

```
<div class="slideshow">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td><div class="icon_circle" ><img src="images/logo_winrar.png" alt="" /><br><figcaption>WinRar</figcaption></div></td>
         <td><div class="icon_circle" ><img src="images/logo_ollydbg.gif" alt="" /><br><figcaption>OllyDBG</figcaption></div></td>
         <td><div class="icon_circle" ><img src="images/logo_norton.png" alt="" /><br><figcaption>NortonAV</figcaption></div></td>    
      </tr>
   </table>
   <p>Lorem ipdrepnt occaecqui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.slideshow {
  margin-top: -50px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.slideshow table {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 13px;
}

.slideshow table tr td {
  text-align: center;
}

.icon_circle {
  transform: scale(0.7);
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  border: #00000099 5px solid;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out, border .5s;
  background: #00000000;
}

.icon_circle:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
  border-radius: 0;
  /* Glitchy border width - Expanding Table - 75px as visual example */
  border-width: 75px;
}
```

Images:
[image: .icon_circle:hover does this]
.icon_circle:hover does this
[image: border-radius: 75px - Expanding my table column.]
I know this isn't onclick but I'm just using :hover to test.

[image: HOW DO I ACHIEVE THIS 'onclick']
HOW DO I ACHIEVE THIS 'onclick'

Comment: `.slideshow table tr td {
  text-align: center;
}` Apply your border style on this.

Comment: But the column's are 30% or something of the page width and dont work with the scaling of the image and it still expands the column.. This is worse than what I originally have.. Thanks anyways :/

Comment: Put up a fiddle so that I can look into it.

Comment: don't use border for this effect. You need 1 element hidden behind the icon and initially having its size matched with the icon's size. On hovering or clicking, that element will expand (the height will go full parent's height, the width will go full parent's width, the left and top will go to 0 - of course that element's position should be `absolute`).

Comment: I'm thinking manually add some space in the actual image so I don't see any clipping when I use border-radius and get rid of the table and lay the images out with margins or something idk but would that possibly work?

Comment: I don't know how to use fiddle.. And how would I position the element so it's contstantly behind the image?

Comment: Definitely as @KingKing said. Have an element behind the icon that is `display: none;` until you click. make sure the parent element is `position:absolute;` and this element is `position:relative;` that way all of it's `Height`, `Width`, `Top`, and `Left`, attributes will be completely relative to it's parent, allowing you to just use `height: 100%; width: 100%;`

Comment: Depending on your browsers compatibility you don't need to add a new element (especially since position:relative does not work well with `<td>`...).

In my opinion you should animate a radial gradient as the background of your `<td>`.